# Problem with imageOverlay layerGroup and zoom levels

Tags: leaflet

Situation:

I have an imageOverlay in a layerGroup.
Zoom level: 16
The png-file is fetched from the server when adding the overlay-layer.

When I zoom in or out, I remove the previous imageOverlay with `removeLayer(imgA)` and a new png-file is fetched from the server, matching the zoom level. This works fine.

But: when I remove the overlay and add the overlay ALL imageOverlays appear again.

It looks like a bug in Leaflet. Or do I have an error in my code?

[imageOverlay re-appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ3jr.jpg)

[overlay control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhNrS.png)

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css"
     integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY="
     crossorigin=""/>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"
     integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo="
     crossorigin=""></script>
<style>
.schermvullend {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    
<div id="map" class="schermvullend"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var url = 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var zoom = 16;
var breedtegraad = '51.561721700355974';
var lengtegraad = '5.072394019517229';
var knooppuntenBool = false;

var osm = L.tileLayer(url, {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
});

var baseMap = 'OpenStreetMap';

var baseMaps = {
    "OpenStreetMap": osm
};

var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [breedtegraad, lengtegraad],
    zoom: zoom,
    layers: [baseMaps[baseMap]]
});

var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps, null, {position: 'bottomleft', collapsed: false}).addTo(map);



var knooppuntenGroup = L.layerGroup();
let knooppuntenName = 'Knooppunten';
layerControl.addOverlay(knooppuntenGroup, knooppuntenName);

var imgA;

function getKnooppunten () {

    let obj = map.getBounds();
    let size = map.getSize();

    let bbox = obj._southWest.lat + ',' + obj._southWest.lng + ',' + obj._northEast.lat + ',' + obj._northEast.lng;
    let imageUrl = 'https://service.pdok.nl/wandelnet/regionale-wandelnetwerken/wms/v1_0?'
        + 'REQUEST=GetMap&'
        + 'SERVICE=WMS&'
        + 'VERSION=1.3.0&'
        + 'FORMAT=image/png&'
        + 'STYLES=&'
        + 'TRANSPARENT=true&'
        + 'layers=wandelnetwerken&'
        + 'WIDTH=' + size.x + '&'
        + 'HEIGHT=' + size.y + '&'
        + 'CRS=EPSG:4326&'
        + 'BBOX=' + bbox;

//        console.log(imageUrl);

    var errorOverlayUrl = 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/110/110686.png';
    var altText = 'Wandelknooppunten';
    var latLngBounds = L.latLngBounds([[obj._southWest.lat, obj._southWest.lng], [obj._northEast.lat, obj._northEast.lng]]);
    
    imgA = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, latLngBounds, {
        opacity: 1,
        errorOverlayUrl: errorOverlayUrl,
        alt: altText,
        interactive: true
    }).addTo(knooppuntenGroup);
}

map.on({
    overlayadd: function(e) {
        if (e.name === knooppuntenName) {
            getKnooppunten ();
            knooppuntenBool = true;
        }
    },
    overlayremove: function(e) {
        if (e.name === knooppuntenName) {
            knooppuntenBool = false;
        }
    },
    moveend: function() {
        if (knooppuntenBool) {
            knooppuntenGroup.removeLayer(imgA);
            getKnooppunten ();
        }
    }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I expect that a layer will be removed persistently when using `removeLayer()`, but something is going wrong when working with overlay-layers.

Comment: You're using a WMS service. Use `L.TileLayer.WMS`.

Comment: Thanks @IvanSanchez, `L.TileLayer.WMS` is now working fine on my test page. But when I add more baseMap layers, the WMS TileLayer disappears behind the basemap. It is loaded though.

```
var baseMaps = {
 "Geopunt": geopunt,
 "Geopunt grijs": geopunt_grijs,
 "Geopunt luchtfoto": luchtfoto,
 "OpenStreetMap": osm
};

var map = L.map('map', {
 center: [breedtegraad, lengtegraad],
 zoom: zoom,
 layers: [baseMaps[baseMap]]
});
```

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/